# django party rental company inventory model

Tags: django, model, relational-database, inventory

A party company rents out chairs, table and tents. These all have a set price, but there are savings if the items are bungled in a package(e.g. Package A includes: one 18x30 tent, 72 chairs and 12 tables). I'm dealing with three different packages: a, b and c. My model so far is as follows.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)

class ItemInventory(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    total = models.DecimalField(decimal_place=2, max_digits=5)
```

So, an **Item** could be a chair, table, 30x40 tent, etc., those items are linked to **ItemInventory** to count how many are left to rent out. An **Order** can include any **Item** of some arbitrary amount. **Order.total** would sum up to be each (**Order.items.price** x quantity).

Question 1, How might I include quantity for each **Item** in an **Order**?

Question 2, Should I make a model for packages or include package logic in views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just my opinion...

An `Item` should probably have a `quantity` field used to keep track of how many are in inventory at a given time. This field gets updated every time an order is placed.

Your "Order" form class needs to validate that for every item in the order, there are enough of that item left, or throw a validation error, or create a back order, etc.

`ItemInventory` should probably change to something like "LineItem" - it represents how many of which item was ordered. It should also probably have a "price" field to record what the price was at the time the order was placed. This model needs a foreign key to `Order`.

If your LineItem doesn't also include the price, and you change the price of the related Item, every single order total could potentially be incorrect if you were just relying on `Item.price`

`Order` doesn't need an "items" field as you can use the `order.lineitem_set.all()` queryset to retrieve these items. You could also use a Sum of the price column on that queryset to generate the total instead of making it a column, but that's subjective.

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of database work for a POS software company, and this is the structure of most of their databases.
- ItemMaster (stores data about the item eg. inventory, price, etc)
- TransactionMaster (stores master data about the transaction (sum, tender, balance, etc)
- TransactionDetail (provides a line for each item in a transaction with TransactionMaster as a foreign key reference)

This method allows you to grab Transactions, then grab the details by the foreign key reference, and the details table will hold the price, quantity, etc for each line item on the invoice. I've seen this method in multiple software, seems to be pretty reliable.